# Writing a dictionary to excel using .to_excel in python

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas.excelwriter

I have a dictionary with a couple floats, an int and a series all in one.  I would like to write this to Excel all on the same sheet.

```
series = df5.copy()

dictionary = {'Avg':2.3534, 'Expected':series, 'Variance':1.01, 'Std. Dev': 1.78, '# of broken parts':300}
```

I have tried two different ways of writing these to Excel, one being straight to Excel where I receive an error saying dict has no .to_excel functionality, and the other method I tried the following:

```
dictionary.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Break Date', index = False)

or

for key in dictionarys.keys():
    dictionary[key].to_excel(writer,sheet_name = key, index = False)
```

I would like the keys of the dictionary to be the title of the columns.

Desired output in Excel on same sheet:

```
Average  Expected   Variance    Std. Dev    # of broken parts
2.3534     2           1.01       1.78          300
           4
           2
           4
```

Comment: `to_excel()` is a method of Pandas DataFrames, not dicts, or dicts' keys. You need to have your data in an actual dataframe to use that method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas library to convert your dictionary to a DataFrame and then write it to an Excel sheet.

First, convert the dictionary to a DataFrame:

`df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)`

Then, use the to_excel method to write the DataFrame to an Excel sheet:

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Break Date', index=False)
```

This will write the DataFrame to the sheet 'Break Date' in your Excel file, with the keys of the dictionary as the column names.

If you want to export all the key-value of the dictionary to the same sheet, you could use the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient='index').transpose()
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Break Date', index=False)
```

This will create a DataFrame where the keys of the dictionary are the columns name and the values of the dictionary are the values of the DataFrame and then export it to the excel sheet.

Comment: What's the difference between the first answer and the second answer here. They both say they will write the dictionary with keys as columns. What is the purpose of `orient='index'` and `.transpose()` in the second solution?

Comment: So when I create a dataframe with this dictionary, the columns fill with the numbers of the first row.  The new dataframe has values in there I do not need so the output is not entirely how I would like.  My example is a short version of a huge dataset so post process is not ideal either.